# looping through a series filenames in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to process some files in a loop. This version is kind of hard coded for testing but my problem is to get the full filename with variables and it looks good to me but the script hangs so obviously I did something silly.  Can anyone help?  Here is my script

```
File_numbers={1003,1004}
File_name=$Domain + "__" + $Domain + "_" + $i "__" + * +  ".ext"
Full_path=$Path + "/" + $Domain + "/" + $File_name

for i in $File_numbers; 
do echo $i; cat $Full_path; 
done
```

If someone has a more elegant solution that would be fine as well.

Update:
I have changed my script as such (based on the issues pointed out by users)

```
#!/bin/bash

Path="aPath";
Domain="aDomain";
File_numbers="{1003,1004}"
Full_path=$Path"/"$Domain"/"

for i in $File_numbers; do find $Full_path -name "*"$i"*" | xargs cat; done
```

it seems that the variable is not recognized in this case

Comment: `bash` and `batch` are not the same! Let us know _exactly_ which environment your are targeting your scripts on.

Comment: @Inian Apparently, this is a `bash` script. However it seems OP has misunderstood the meaning.

Comment: @badner: **BATCH** is a kind of Windows script, while **BASH** is a Unix script.

Comment: Think: What's the value of `$i` while you define `File_name`?

Comment: sorry I was using it to mean "a bunch" of files NOT a .bat.  I will change the title, it is a bash script.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out @Inian

Comment: @Stephan this is the issue.  $i I just want to be file numbers but they are nested in a structure like aDomain__aDomain_1034__someInformation.extension

Comment: If the files are already on the disk, in reality you want to do something like `find aDomain -name 'whatever' | xargs cat`, and don't bother with setting variables and tracking loop state by hand..

Comment: This fails (in part) for the same reason `{1,$x}` would fail; brace expansion occurs *before* parameter expansion (and in this case, not at all on the right-hand side of an assignment).

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net, and find a good tutorial writing shell scripts; `+` is not a string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would do (fixing a bunch of minor issues):

```
#!/bin/bash
Path="aPath"
Domain="aDomain"
File_numbers="[1003|1004]"
Full_path="$Path/$Domain/"

find $Full_path -name "*$File_numbers*" | xargs cat
```

So what I changed:

- no ; in bash !
- no need to loop on File_numbers.  *[1003|1004]* means anything including 1003, or 1004.
- notice how -name "*$File_numbers*" contains everything within the ""
- Full_path: variables are usable within double quotes (").

Finally, I *strongly* suggest you do a quick google search and find a beginners guide to bash, it will save you a LOT of time!  Invest now or waist time later!